# Ubuntu Budgie 23.04 wont boot to desktop after nvidia driver install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I’ve tried installing the nVidia driver, originally 525, then when presented with a system freeze after the pcieport … messages in the console, I purged them and was able to get back in.

I then tried version 510, but this time I also used the nvidia-xconfig command after. This time, the entire system was completely unresponsive even in recovery mode, most keypresses werent evem detected in the console.

I managed to do the purge again after swithing to iGPU as the initial display in BIOS at which point the system was responsive again.

I could then still get into desktop using Intel integrated graphics, but when switching back to nVidia GPU in the BIOS, the problem returns.

i deleted the xorg.conf file that was created in the process, but theres no change.

Lastly, I tried installing nVidia 530 drivers from their website directly, but again theres no difference.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Just to confirm that you're running wiith Nvidia card installed on your system, run `sudo lspci -v | grep -i vga` and edit your question to include the output. This will provide details of the video device in question. Also, was Ubuntu running successfully before attempting to install the Nvidia drivers? Thanks

Comment: @richbl I'm pasting what I managed to figure out later from Ubuntu Budgie forum. https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/23-04-wont-finish-normal-boot-with-nvidia-drivers/6730